# Remove only those whitespaces which are appeared after each comma from a string in bash

Tags: bash

I am new in bash and would like to know best way to remove those white spaces which are available after each comma in string. For e.g. I have following input string :

```
abc, xyz,  cdf axy bnz cnm
```

Resultant string should be :

```
abc,xyz,cdf axy bnz cnm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` for this

```
$ sed -E 's/, +/,/g' input_file
abc,xyz,cdf axy bnz cnm
```

Comment: sed 's/, */,/g'

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the [`extglob` option](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) and do it with parameter expansion pattern replacement:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str="abc, xyz,  cdf axy bnz cnm"
shopt -s extglob
printf "%s\n" "${str//,+([[:space:]])/,}"
```